# How to get Register Graph API results in XML format?

Tags: xml, rest, api, graph

At Register Graph API documentation site (https://developers.ir.ee/graph-api) there are examples for getting request responses for the REST service in JSON format. Is there also support for XML?

Answer (score 0):

Add suffix .xml to the end of requests such as in the following (if the basic query is https://graph.ir.ee/organizations/ee-10722958/members):

```
curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic XXXXX" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" https://graph.ir.ee/organizations/ee-10722958/members.xml
```

Comment: For RDF/XML serialization use .rdf suffix such as in `curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic XXXXX" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" https://graph.ir.ee/organizations/ee-10722958/members.rdf`